# Solidity: Why does a faulty input set my boolean to "true"?

Tags: boolean, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I'm using remix.ethereum.org

I wrote this very simple smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract TicTacToe {
    bool myBool = false;

    uint8 myUint8;
    uint256 myUint256;

    string myString = "myString";
    bytes myBytes = "myString";

    function setMyBoolean(bool myBoolArgument) public {
        myBool = myBoolArgument;
    }

    function getMyBoolean() public view returns(bool) {
      return myBool;
    }

}
```

As you can see the default value for `myBool` is **false**
I can change this by calling the function `setMyBoolean`.

If I use this argument and type in **true**, `myBool` will be set to **true** 
If I use this argument and type in **false**, `myBool` will be set to **false**

But if I type in any other combination of letters, `myBool` will be set to **true** as well. This surprises me because the default setting for `myBool` is **false**.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 2):

It's working as intended because this is the way that remix and abi encoder decided to handle booleans

```
  // "false" will be converting to `false` and "true" will be working
  // fine as abiCoder assume anything in quotes as `true`
  if (type === 'bool' && args[i] === 'false') {
     args[i] = false
  }
```

https://github.com/ethereum/remix/blob/807ffd9772b07dafb343c08faf44c78ee456de77/remix-lib/src/execution/txHelper.js#L18

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the value input is evaluated as as a string and, as the string exists and It Is not empty, It Is evaluated as true.